# Subquery returned more than 1 value. the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server

I am facing issue:

**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

if and else if condition work fine but else condition not work.
and show issue in SQL server:

[image]

```html
alter proc spSearch  'Cook','205'
(
@SearchName Nvarchar(Max),
@AdminStatus nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin
Declare @SearchRecipeKey AS Nvarchar(Max)
Declare @SearchChefKey AS Nvarchar(Max)
SET @SearchRecipeKey = (SELECT  Recipes.RecipeName FROM Recipes WHERE Recipes.RecipeName LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%')
SET @SearchChefKey = (SELECT Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName as FullName FROM Chef WHERE (Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName) LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%')
if((@SearchRecipeKey IS NOT NULL) and (@SearchChefKey IS NULL))
    Begin
  select Recipes.RecipeId, Recipes.RecipeName, 1 as Flag from Recipes       
        where Recipes.RecipeName LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%'
       and Recipes.AdminStatus=@AdminStatus ORDER BY Recipes.RecipeName ASC;
  End
  else if ((@SearchRecipeKey IS  NULL) and (@SearchChefKey IS NOT NULL))
  Begin
  select Chef.ChefId,Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName as FullName, uinfo.UserType,Chef.EmailId, 2 as Flag  from Recipes
       inner join Chef on Recipes.ChefId = Chef.ChefId 
        full join Users uinfo on Chef.EmailId = uinfo.EmailId
        where (Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName) LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%'
       and Recipes.AdminStatus=@AdminStatus ORDER BY  FullName ASC;
  End
  else 
    Begin
  select Recipes.RecipeId, Recipes.RecipeName,Chef.ChefId,Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName as FullName, uinfo.UserType,Chef.EmailId, 3 as Flag  from Recipes
       inner join Chef on Recipes.ChefId = Chef.ChefId 
        inner join Users uinfo on Chef.EmailId = uinfo.EmailId
         where (Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName) LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%' or Recipes.RecipeName LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%'
       and Recipes.AdminStatus=@AdminStatus ORDER BY Recipes.RecipeName, FullName ASC;
  End
 
  End
```

Comment: I can't see the code in your screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use  `Select TOP 1` in your Query.

**TOP 1 Select Only 1st Value in your Query.**

```
alter proc spSearch  'Cook','205'
(
@SearchName Nvarchar(Max),
@AdminStatus nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin
Declare @SearchRecipeKey AS Nvarchar(Max)
Declare @SearchChefKey AS Nvarchar(Max)
SET @SearchRecipeKey = (SELECT TOP 1  Recipes.RecipeName FROM Recipes WHERE Recipes.RecipeName LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%')
SET @SearchChefKey = (SELECT TOP 1 Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName as FullName FROM Chef WHERE (Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName) LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%')
if((@SearchRecipeKey IS NOT NULL) and (@SearchChefKey IS NULL))
    Begin
        select Recipes.RecipeId, Recipes.RecipeName, 1 as Flag from Recipes       
        where Recipes.RecipeName LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%'
       and Recipes.AdminStatus=@AdminStatus ORDER BY Recipes.RecipeName ASC;
     End
     else if ((@SearchRecipeKey IS  NULL) and (@SearchChefKey IS NOT NULL))
     Begin
     select Chef.ChefId,Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName as FullName, uinfo.UserType,Chef.EmailId, 2 as Flag  from Recipes
       inner join Chef on Recipes.ChefId = Chef.ChefId 
        full join Users uinfo on Chef.EmailId = uinfo.EmailId
        where (Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName) LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%'
       and Recipes.AdminStatus=@AdminStatus ORDER BY  FullName ASC;
     End
     else 
    Begin
        select Recipes.RecipeId, Recipes.RecipeName,Chef.ChefId,Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName as FullName, uinfo.UserType,Chef.EmailId, 3 as Flag  from Recipes
       inner join Chef on Recipes.ChefId = Chef.ChefId 
        inner join Users uinfo on Chef.EmailId = uinfo.EmailId
         where (Chef.FirstName+' '+Chef.LastName) LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%' or Recipes.RecipeName LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%'
       and Recipes.AdminStatus=@AdminStatus ORDER BY Recipes.RecipeName, FullName ASC;
     End

     End
```

Comment: Warning: `SELECT TOP` **without** an `ORDER BY` selects an arbitrary number of rows - you're not telling SQL Server **what** to order by, to get the `TOP` rows, after all !